# MySQL Include in any case a column even if it's also part of JOIN clause

Tags: mysql, join, case

this is my query, apart Wordpress prefix, it's just a matter of MySQL.

Scroll to WHERE CLAUSE when you will find all the options.
basically give me back all the results wether `$searchString` is either in the *post_title*, OR in the postmeta field called “*operations_long_bio*" OR “*operations_**short**_bio*"

this is working quite as expected but I would also like to have in the results, in any case ALWAYS the content of the column whose meta_key value is “operations_**short**_bio"

```
SELECT
                       posts.post_title AS name, posts.ID as ID,
                       postmeta.meta_value AS description
                    FROM `{$wpdb->base_prefix}posts` AS posts
                    LEFT JOIN `{$wpdb->base_prefix}postmeta` AS postmeta
                        ON posts.ID=postmeta.post_id
                    WHERE
                          posts.post_type = 'post'
                          AND
                            posts.post_status = 'publish'
                          AND
                          (
                                (
                                    postmeta.meta_key
                                     IN('operations_long_bio', 'operations_short_bio')
                                     AND postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%$searchStr%'
                                )
                              OR ( posts.post_title LIKE '%$searchStr%' )
                         )
                    GROUP BY posts.ID
            ");
```

I tried forcing:

```
SELECT
                       posts.post_title AS name, posts.ID as ID,
                       postmeta.meta_value AS description
/***********/
CASE postmeta.meta_key='operations_short_bio' THEN postmeta.meta_value AS short_description END
...
```

but throws an error.
don't really actually know how to ask "give me ALSO the field *postmeta.meta_value AS short_description* WHEN it's *postmeta.meta_key='operations_short_bio'* :(

any hint?

tyvm!!

Answer (score 1):

The [Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html) is correctly in this form

```
CASE WHEN postmeta.meta_key='operations_short_bio' THEN postmeta.meta_value  END AS short_description
```

And here is an example from your query, iha to adept it a litte, as this is not php

> ```
> CREATE TABLE posts (ID int,post_title varchar(100), post_type varchar(10),post_status varchar(10))
> ```

> ```
> CREATE tABLE postmeta (post_id int,meta_key varchar(100),meta_value varchar(100))
> ```

> ```
> SELECT CASE WHEN postmeta.meta_key='operations_short_bio' THEN postmeta.meta_value  END AS short_description
> FROM postmeta
> ```

> ```
> | short_description |
> | :---------------- |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>                        posts.post_title AS name, posts.ID as ID,
>                        postmeta.meta_value AS description,
>                        MAX(CASE WHEN postmeta.meta_key='operations_short_bio' THEN postmeta.meta_value  END) AS short_description
>                     FROM `posts` AS posts
>                     LEFT JOIN `postmeta` AS postmeta
>                         ON posts.ID=postmeta.post_id
>                     WHERE
>                           posts.post_type = 'post'
>                           AND
>                             posts.post_status = 'publish'
>                           AND
>                           (
>                                 (
>                                     postmeta.meta_key
>                                      IN('operations_long_bio', 'operations_short_bio')
>                                      AND postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%$searchStr%'
>                                 )
>                               OR ( posts.post_title LIKE '%$searchStr%' )
>                          )
>                     GROUP BY posts.ID,posts.post_title,postmeta.meta_value
> ```
>
> ```
> name | ID | description | short_description
> :--- | -: | :---------- | :----------------
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0fb5a1ad281f4c38f091f6a1a5990d0b)*

Comment: nope :( there's an error somewhere over the rainbow :D
`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE WHEN postmeta.meta_key='operations_short_bio' THEN postmeta.meta_value END ' at line 4`

Comment: no as you can see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9df8395176ecd3da2fe45adb3e899880 this works with out a problem, you have in your code another error

Comment: hello again, sorry for previous post, as I was missing a comma.
amnyways, I pasted your code, BUT, unfortunately short_description field is always empty even when it is filled.

`[0] => Array
        (
            [name] => XXX
            [ID] => 542
            [description] => lorem ipsum respiro di dolor.
            [short_description] => // SHOULD BE FILLED 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Amici di matteo
            [ID] => 585
            [description] => Questi siamo noi, gli Amici di Matteo!
           [short_description] =>
        )
`

Comment: please don't post code make a dbfiddle like mine and post there your queries, so that i can check. The example shows that my code works. so please make a fiddle

Comment: yes sorry. don't know why they keep comments rather than a forum approach. I edited you fiddle, to take into account the two different fields (and also had to edit the group by clause) since it was generating non-aggregated error: [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=45a789254215f2ccc8f7ea6daf2afa95)

Comment: link is broken post only the without anything please

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=83b0977208c22cd860b7a470dd08c434

Comment: no way :(
don't know why, with ACF on WP it's not working. `$searchStr = preg_replace('/\s+/', '%', $_GET['s']);  $searchStr = "%".$searchStr."%";` it's the only difference compared to our fiddle [link] (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=88bd0e2b4c69e26762fe7003173f524f)

Comment: $searchStr is a php variable mysql treats that as normal text,.

Comment: yes, I am doing this to convert  "some string" to "%some%string%" and pass to LIKE compare...
the matter is that locally is not working and keeps giving back either of the results, empty...